# Jupyter Notebook Packages Won't Import

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I've searched around for a while, and I've tried many things such as

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py3 python=3 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py3    # On Windows, remove the word 'source'
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Uninstalling and reinstall both Python3 and Anaconda3.  All I want is for Jupyter Notebook to be able to use libraries in Anaconda.   If I change my environment to root via

```
activate root
```

I can open Jupyter notebook, however when I do

```
activate ipykernel_py3
```

and then try to do

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the error

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2
```

When I open Jupyter notebook and input

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

I get
'C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Mathematical Modeling'

and Anaconda is in 
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

The problem is when I do

```
import numpy
```

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a0bd626bb1d> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

--------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------

I've just uninstalled anaconda, and am currently reinstalling it.  For some reason I was unable to install other packages to my ipykernel_py3 environment.  Hopefully I figure something out.

Comment: I think numpy is not installed for the ipykernel_py3 environment, so after you activate it, install numpy like using "conda install -c anaconda numpy"

Comment: Okay that exact command didn't work, but from the website, https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

conda install --name ipykernel_py3 numpy

worked.  Now just to install all packages

Answer (score 0):

The solution after countless re-installations of anaconda, and working with environments, is this

Go to start menu->
View Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables

highlight the variable that has name 'Path'

Click edit

Change variable value to 'C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda3\Scripts'

Of course my directory will be different from anyone else's, but this solved all my problems.